# Sorting Records on the Basis of Number of Items in a Group- SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a set of records and I want to sort these records on the basis of the number of items in a group.

[image: The below image is a snapshot of the table]

I want to arrange the records in such a way that Products with maximum number of items are at the top i.e. the required order is-  Product_ID 3 (with 6 items), then Product_ID 1 (with 5 items) and the last one would be Product_ID 2(with 3 items).

The following query returns the count of the items with same Product_ID, however, I want Item_Name, Item_Description and Item_Number to be arranged as well.

```
Select Product_ID, Count(*) from Product group by Product_ID order by Count(*) DESC
```

I have tried another query as follows, but I know I am wrong somewhere that it is not giving the desired results and I can't think of a possible solution:

```
Select Product_ID, Item_Name, Item_Description, Item_Number from Product 
group by Product_ID,item_name,item_description,item_number 
order by COUNT(product_ID)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select Product_ID, Item_Name, Item_Description, Item_Number
from Product 
order by COUNT(1) over (partition by Product_ID) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to group by the ID only but you want to list all other fields, you don't need to group by at all if you just want to order by:

```
SELECT product_id, 
       item_name, 
       item_description, 
       item_number 
FROM   product p1 
ORDER  BY (SELECT Count(product_id) 
           FROM   product p2 
           WHERE  p1.product_id = p2.product_id) DESC
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I won't need group by and the query works exactly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an alias:

```
Select Product_ID, Count(*) AS num_products from Product group by Product_ID order by num_products DESC;
```